# matlab: Graph 2d lines on x,y and z axis in a 3d plot

Tags: matlab, plot

Given a complex signal I have 3 dimensions: I-real part, Q-imaginary part, T-time.
I have been able to use the:

```
plot3(I,T,Q)
```

to plot the signal in matlab. I would now like to add the Q-imaginary part line graph to the z-plane and the I-real part line graph to the x,y plane. How can I add the additional lines to the graph? I included a picture of what I want it to look like:

[image]

What I have so far is this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commented code below:

```
% hold on for multiple plots
figure(1)
hold on

% Plot 3D Figure
plot3(I,T,Q) 

% Plot on XY plane - means function in Z = 0
plot3(I,T,Q.*0)

% Plot on YZ plane - means function in X = 0
plot(I.*0,T,Q)

hold off
```

In your case the planes being plotted on aren't actually the axes' zeros. You may want to set the zero vector in each 2D plot to be any single-valued vector, which you can make the correct length by methods like this:

```
% vector of 2s the same size as Q
A = (Q./Q).*2;
% or
A = ones(size(Q)).*2;
% or 
A = A.*0 + 2;
```

For instance, plotting a similar function to your image:

```
x = linspace(0,20,1000);

hold on
plot3(sin(x),x,cos(x))
plot3(sin(x),x,cos(x).*0 - 1)
plot3(sin(x).*0 + 1,x,cos(x))
grid on
hold off
```

[image: 3D function with 2D plots]

Comment: Why the need for -1 and +1?

Comment: @EliMiller As I try to explain in the middle of my answer, they are to shift the plots to the planes `z=-1` or `x=+1`. If they were zeros, all plots would intersect. Try it yourself! So purely an aesthetic thing...

Comment: is there a way to get the time T instead of 0-20 to go from 20 to 0?

Comment: I was able to make the YZ plane equal to all -1 to shift the line graph to the from then I rotated the graph.

Comment: Your plot doesn't go from 0 to 20?

Comment: I was justs wanting the time axis T to go from 0 to 20. The graph you plated goes from 20 to 0.

Comment: @EliMiller after plotting: `set(gca,'YDir','Reverse')`

Comment: The time is now plotted correctly by using the set(gca,'YDir','Reverse').

Comment: "Correctly" is subjective... the standard axes orientation would be as MATLAB's default was without reversing the `Y` axis...  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#Three_dimensions You might be better of simply rotating your plot.