# Plot3 function with different graphs

Tags: plot, matlab-figure, gaussian, surf, scatter

I want to do something similar to this: [matlab: Graph 2d lines on x,y and z axis in a 3d plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41724135/matlab-graph-2d-lines-on-x-y-and-z-axis-in-a-3d-plot)

But the thing is that I don't need to plot any 3D graph, just need to use the XY, XZ and YZ planes to plot:

Plane XY - I have 2 multivariate PDF contour in this plane (2 contours!)

```
T=contour(panico.back(1).grids_db.X1,...
         panico.back(1).grids_db.X2,panico.back(1).grids_db.Pdf2,'linewidth',2); 

hold on
Q=contour(PEC.back(1).grids_db.X1,...
          PEC.back(1).grids_db.X2,PEC.back(1).grids_db.Pdf2,'linewidth',2);

size( PEC.back(1).grids_db.Pdf1 ) = [180 180];
size( panico.back(1).grids_db.Pdf1 ) = [180 180];
size( PEC.back(1).grids_db.Pdf2 ) = [180 180];
size( panico.back(1).grids_db.Pdf2 ) = [180 180];
```

Plane XZ - two normal plots with 2 gaussian curves;

```
plot(PEC.back(1).grids_db.X1,PEC.back(1).grids_db.Pdf2(:,91),...
     CFC.back(1).grids_db.X1,CFC.back(1).grids_db.Pdf2(:,91)); hold on

size(PEC.back(1).grids_db.X1) = [1 180]
size(PEC.back(1).grids_db.Pdf2(:,91)) = [180 1]
```

Plane YZ - two normal plots with 2 gaussian curves (just different from XZ).

```
plot(PEC.back(1).grids_db.X2,PEC.back(1).grids_db.Pdf2(:,91),...
     CFC.back(1).grids_db.X2,CFC.back(1).grids_db.Pdf2(:,91));

size( PEC.back(1).grids_db.X1 ) = [1 180]
size( PEC.back(1).grids_db.Pdf2(:,91) ) = [180 1]
```

I've been trying to use the plot3() function but without any success due to different plots handling.

See the figure for a better understanding of the final output (plot3 with different graphs)

[image]

Can anyone help me with this, please?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What do you mean with _without any success due to different plots handling_? Waht is the problem with the _plot handling_? Could you post your code?

Comment: @il_raffa

I just added the code! It's everything I have so far!

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me with this?